# Cant come up with a NSPredicate that gets the entities i want?

Tags: iphone, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I have a datamodel with three entities which looks like:

```
Event:
id
startTime
->>invitees

User:
id
type
->>invitations  (Invitees entity)

Invitees:
rsvpState
->user
->event
```

-> = to-one relationship

->> = too-many relationship

What i am trying to do is create a predicate that returns all the events that a user of a certain type and id has rsvp'd "Y" to and have a startTime greater than now. The closest i have come so far is:

SUBQUERY(invitees.user, $x, $x.id == %i AND $x.type == %i).invitations.rsvpState == %@ AND startTime > %@

This doesn't give me any errors although i am still getting strange results. I guess i dont fully understand how subqueries work.

1. For example when doing .invitations.rsvpSate == %@ is that checking that ALL users who passes the predicate has an invitation.rsvpState == "Y" or is it checking the resulting collection of users to see if ANY of them have an invitation.rsvpState == "Y".
2. By adding startTime > %@ to the end of the query does that check if ALL resulting events have a startTime > %@ or that ANY of the events in the results has a startTime > %@?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is easier to use `NSCompoundPredicate`s rater than `SUBQUERY`. It would help you split up your query and be more readable.

As for your 2 questions, the answer is always ALL. There is also the predicate keyword `ANY` in case you need "any".

Assuming that the `id` of `User` is unique, you do not need the `type` property. Also, I am not sure you actually need a compound predicate or subquery. Please try:

```
startTime > %@ AND invitees.user.id == %i AND invitees.rsvpState == %@
```